# FireDAC BatchMove from MemoryTable

Tags: delphi, firedac

My incoming data is loaded in a TFDMemTable, (the reader). The writer is a TFDQuery.

Incoming data should be inserted if not in the target, otherwise updated. Matches are based on the UUID field.

I am unable to properly define that the UUID field is the key.

Here is a code example - does not work. FBatchMove.Execute fails because cannot it find any key fields.

```
procedure TSubDB.FindDestRecord(ASender: TObject; var AFound: Boolean);
var
  aSrc: TBytes;
begin
  SetLength(aSrc, 16);
  aSrc := FReader.DataSet.FieldByName('UUID').AsBytes;
  AFound := FWriter.DataSet.Locate('UUID', aSrc, []);
end;

function TSubDB.LoadDB(const aFilename: string): boolean;
var
  FQry: TFDQuery;
  FBatchMove: TFDBatchMove;
  FReader: TFDBatchMoveDataSetReader;
  FWriter: TFDBatchMoveDataSetWriter;
  FMemTable: TFDMemTable;
begin
  FQry := TFDQuery.Create(nil);
  FQry.Connection := dmFB.myDB;
  FQry.FetchOptions.AssignedValues := [evItems];
  FQry.FetchOptions.Items := [fiBlobs, fiDetails];
  FBatchMove := TFDBatchMove.Create(nil);
  FBatchMove.Analyze := [taDelimSep, taHeader, taFields];
  FReader := TFDBatchMoveDataSetReader.Create(FBatchMove);
  FWriter := TFDBatchMoveDataSetWriter.Create(FBatchMove);
  FMemTable := TFDMemTable.Create(nil);
  try
    FMemTable.LoadFromFile(aFileName, sfBinary);
    //Not sure how to make the BatchMove recognize that UUID is the key for OnFindDestRecord
    FMemTable.IndexFieldNames := 'UUID';
    with FMemTable.Indexes.Add do
    begin
      Name :='idxUUID';
      Fields := 'UUID';
      Active := true;
    end;
    FMemTable.IndexName := 'idxUUID';
    FMemTable.IndexesActive := true;
    FMemTable.FieldByName('UUID').ProviderFlags := FMemTable.FieldByName('UUID').ProviderFlags + [pfInKey];
    FReader.DataSet := FMemTable;
    FQry.SQL.Text := 'select * from test';
    FWriter.DataSet := FQry;
    FBatchMove.OnFindDestRecord := FindDestRecord;
    FBatchMove.Mode := dmAppendUpdate;
    //None of the above seems to keep the pfInKey in the UUID field's ProviderFlags
    FBatchMove.Execute;
    FQry.Open;
    FQry.Close;
  finally
    FMemTable.Free;
    FWriter.Free;
    FReader.Free;
    FBatchMove.Free;
    FQry.Free;
  end;
end;
```

I would really appreciate a working example of batch move (where the target has data, so the batch move mode is dmAppendUpdate).

Comment: For dmAppendUpdate mode you need PK in writers dataset. So, you need include fiMeta into FQry.FetchOptions.Items and to have PK defined in "test" table. Or define PK in FQry by hands. In any case your code is too excessive ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key here is that the writer needs to be a TFDBatchMoveSQLWriter with a TableName set. This way the destination had the primary key defined and it is then used to decide whether to insert or update.

```
function TSubDB.LoadDB(const aFilename: string): boolean;
var
  FQry: TFDQuery;
  FBatchMove: TFDBatchMove;
  FReader: TFDBatchMoveDataSetReader;
  FWriter: TFDBatchMoveSQLWriter;
  FMemTable: TFDMemTable;
begin
  FQry := TFDQuery.Create(nil);
  FQry.Connection := dmFB.myDB;
  FQry.FetchOptions.AssignedValues := [evItems];
  FQry.FetchOptions.Items := [fiBlobs, fiDetails];
  FBatchMove := TFDBatchMove.Create(nil);
  FBatchMove.Analyze := [taDelimSep, taHeader, taFields];
  FReader := TFDBatchMoveDataSetReader.Create(FBatchMove);
  FWriter := TFDBatchMoveSQLWriter.Create(FBatchMove);
  FMemTable := TFDMemTable.Create(nil);
  try
    FMemTable.LoadFromFile(aFileName, sfBinary);
    FReader.DataSet := FMemTable;
    FQry.SQL.Text := 'select * from test';
    FWriter.Connection := dmFB.myDB;
    FWriter.TableName := 'test';
    FBatchMove.Mode := dmAppendUpdate;
    FBatchMove.Execute;
    FQry.Open;
    FQry.Close;
  finally
    FMemTable.Free;
    FWriter.Free;
    FReader.Free;
    FBatchMove.Free;
    FQry.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: da-soft is also right. As long as the writer had a PK defined, all is well.

Comment: I'm curious, what does FQry.Open followed by FQry.Close do here?  Is it needed for FBatchMove to insert/update the test table?